# Filter columns based on a matched row

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, conditional-statements, dynamic-list

I basically want to achieve the following:

1. Find the row based on a cell value
2. Output the column names, however
3. Filter the column names based on the cell values in the row

So I have a list of clients in column A (listed in rows) and a list of e-learning courses on 15 adjacent columns (listed in a single row). I have a dropdown list with the clients. I want to output a list of e-learning courses after I choose a single client, and the list has to be filtered based on the cell value (1 for „This course is completed“, 0 for „This course has not been completed“). I want to output the non-completed courses only.

The matrix looks as follows:
[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cntkb.png)

So, I could manage to output the row with the 0s and 1s, but I actually want the courses (Row 3) to be output. And how can I filter them based on a condition (if cell value in the found row is 0, then output the column name in row 3)?

Why do I need this? Some clients want to know which courses need to be completed, so I want to have a dynamic list which I can output just by choosing the client’s ID in column A.

Any idea how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with xlookup and filter like this:

```
=FILTER(B3:E3,XLOOKUP(H3,A4:A7,B4:E7)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Gosh, didn’t think it was that easy! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Of course you can transpose it as you have done if you prefer it vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$3:$Q$3; 
  (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(XMATCH($T$5;$A$4:$A$84)+3;2)&":"
  &ADDRESS(XMATCH($T$5;$A$4:$A$84)+3;17)))=0))
```